# To merge 2 column headers in crosstab in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel, crosstab

I want to merge column headers given in the picture to get the (Name) cell in between them..
The 2 column headers that I am talking about are Person and 
2009-10 
Male    Female

I have tried out many ways but nothing works.

P.S it shows accurate output in PDF, but in XLS, it isn't giving what I need.

[image: Output in PDF]

Comment: lots of screen shot but I have not really understood what you need, some freehand circles maybe will help